# Why my phone keep restarting apps?

Tags: performance, xiaomi

When i play game, my phone always restart the game every few minutes to the first screen. It is same when i play a video it is always blinking and skip few seconds every few minutes. It is so annoying when my phone restart some apps every few minutes. Plase help me find solution

Answer (score 0):

First thing you do is fully wipe your phone data/Factory Reset.

Still get random reboot? Check your Xiaomi ROM you used. It's `Global,China, Global Dev, China Dev, or Distributor ROM`

How to do that? Go to Settings - About Phone - MIUI Version
If your ROM is distributor version, the version code will like `66.44.33` If it's BETA ROM the version name will be `MIUI 7.3.2 | Beta` and for the global is `MIUI 8.3 Global`

After you know what's ROM inside your phone. you can re-flashing the ROM that you can download [here](http://en.miui.com/download.html)

How? after you downloaded the ROM, move the downloaded ROM into your phone storage then open Updater App, click the three dots button on the top right side than choose Update package, selected the ROM you have been downloaded. Start flashing wait till finished. Your data will not be wipe if you on the same ROM version `BETA - BETA` or `Global - Global`

**IF** your ROM is Distributor version you must search the same China ROM version like your Distributor ROM version.